# How to convert proc transpose functionality in SAS to Snowflake

Tags: sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on converting SAS code to Snowflake and I got a scenario to implement "PROC TRANSPOSE" functionality in Snowflake. Below is the same table data I have in snowflake and I need to transpose rows into columns and columns into rows at a time.

Sample Input Data:

[image: 1]

Sample Output Data:

[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't post data as images, then if we wanted to post an actual solution we'd have to type out your data. Please review the guidelines here [ask]

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain it what way it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://libguides.library.kent.edu/SAS/TransposeData

The snowflake equivalent is: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=inputDataset OUT=outputDataset;
    BY variable(s);
    COPY variable(s);
    ID variable;
    VAR variable(s);
RUN;
```

VS:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
   PIVOT ( <aggregate_function> ( <pivot_column> )
            FOR <value_column> IN ( <pivot_value_1> [ , <pivot_value_2> ... ] ) )

[ ... ]
```

Comment: I tried with Pivot and Unpivot but I couldn't able to convert both columns to rows and rows to columns at the same time. And also for using Pivot we need to an aggregate function for sure which in my case i have only COL_NM for it.

Comment: Then I suggest that you don't translate the SAS code 1:1 and instead create maybe two seperate tables and then join them together. I never translated SAS functions directly to databases, I looked for alternatives instead ;)

Comment: A pivot may take two steps here - agreed. One to long format and then one back to wide, this is common.